# Probability Theory: Maximizing the difference between distribution functions

Tags: probability, distribution, risk-models

Given a sample of observations $X$, by changing a parameter $p$ we can divide  $X$ into two subsamples $X_1$ and $X_2$ (this division is done in a non-trivial way which is nonetheless irrelevant to the problem at hand). We would like to find a value of $p$ for which subsamples $X_1$ and $X_2$ are as much as possible "distinct". To this purpose, we can consider how "far" apart the empirical distribution functions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are. I am deciding between two objective functions:

1- $max_p \{max_x (\mid F_{X_1}(x)- F_{X_2}(x)\mid)\}$

2- $max_p \{\sum_x (\mid F_{X_1}(x) -  F_{X_2}(x)\mid)\}$,

i.e., the first maximization problem searches for a value of $p$ that maximizes the biggest absolute difference between the EDFs, while the second one chooses a value of $p$ for which the area between the graphs of EDFs is maximized.

I acknowledge that the notion of distinctness might be ambiguous, however, I am looking for pros and cons of each objective functions and if there is any similar problem studied in the literature.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most useful thing I can suggest is to move this post to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

---

You are focusing on maximizing the difference in empirical distribution functions. If you sort your data, and assign the lower values to $X_1$ and the higher values to $X_2$, I believe your *empirical distribution* differences in the given sample would be maximized.

If the objective is to infer two distinct generating processes, for example a "typical" generating process $X_1 \sim N(0,1)$ and an "outlier" generating process $X_2 \sim N(0,100)$, focusing on the *empirical distribution* differences would not tease these two processes apart.  A more typical analytic step would be to determine which distribution ($X_1$ or $X_2$) was more likely to have generated a given observation $x_i$. The statistical distance between these two parameterized generating distributions (and prior for "typical" vs "outlier" in a Bayesian framework) would determine the difficulty of the labeling task $x_i \in X_1$ or $x_i \in X_2$.

Given your model assumptions, and inference from the sample data, the distance between the parameterized generating distributions is fixed $-$ it doesn't make sense to talk about maximizing the distance between probability distributions *given the sample data* and labels $x_i \in X_1$ or $x_i \in X_2$.

If you are allowed to select different features, or transformations of the sample data, you may be able to find very distinct distributions ("good features" for your classification task).

A common measure of the distance between distributions is the Kullback–Leibler divergence.

The expectation–maximization algorithm ("EM algorithm") is commonly used in machine learning for similar tasks (attributing an observation to a generating distribution and estimating the parameters of the generating distributions).